# How do I remove the names created by "layoutit"

Tags: html, css

I was recommended to use [LayoutIt](https://www.layoutit.com/) to create a grid pattern for my website.

However, in the grids I created there are letters in it that I would like to remove but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to edit.

I've made a quick example here - https://codepen.io/awersss/pen/KKpjgzZ?editable=true

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-container *:after {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "l n n n" "l p p p" "l p p p";
}

.n {
  grid-area: n;
}

.l {
  grid-area: l;
}

.p {
  grid-area: p;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="n"></div>
  <div class="l"></div>
  <div class="p"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What names? grid-container?

Comment: In my example, it would be the letters n l and p.

Comment: do you mean the letters p, l and n?

Comment: On your CSS code file, edit this fields: grid-template-areas: then each grid area, then under your HTML page add the new names of those fields in there replacing the previous names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line

```
content:attr(class);
```

from the CSS rule for `.grid-container *:after`

It causes the class names to be displayed as the content of those elements.

ADDITION:

Actually you can even remove the whole `.grid-container *:after` CSS rule, if you don't need it for anything else. The only thing it does is that it adds those letters...